await Task.Delay(1) in OnInitializedAsync() never returning
This is in code that has been running fine for months. No changes. And all pages except 1 come up fine. But this one page, which has:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    // commented out to remove that as a cause
    // IsLoading = true;
    await Task.Delay(1);

    // ...

The purpose of the IsLoading is it makes a loading... spinner visible. I have the exact same set of code for most of my pages - works on the rest.
The Task.Delay(1) never returns. If I comment it out, then the first await calling the DB (via EF) doesn't return.
If I don't call await base.OnInitializedAsync(), then the Task.Delay(1) returns instantly. This is ComponentBase.OnInitializedAsync().
What can cause this? I don't see how there can be deadlock as this is the first await inside  OnInitializedAsync and so there's nothing that can also be waiting.
Update:
The spinner is in this page's razor as:
<ExLoading Visible="@IsLoading" />

And that component is:
<DxLoadingPanel Visible="@Visible"
                PositionTarget="body"
                IsContentBlocked="true"
                ApplyBackgroundShading="true" />

The <DxLoadingPanel> is a DevExpress component.

Can you share the razor part that is rendered when IsLoading is true?

@MayurEkbote Good suggestion. I commented IsLoading out so that is not an issue. Still have the problem. thanks

If you comment out IsLoading then wouldn't the part that is not ready to be rendered be rendered?

@MayurEkbote No as IsLoading is false. There may be something in the razor file (the page has a ton of components in it), but how can that stop a Task.Delay() call? And if I skip that call, then block on the first EntityFramework await? If this code is executing, I don't understand how a call in it, that has no relationship to the razor page, can deadlock on an await.

There are two ways in which loading flags are used. One is if(IsLoading){}else{} the other is if(IsLoading){}. If there is a deadlock in  render logic, the exception will be never thrown on the render side and your debug pointer will be forever stuck on the code part. That is the only thing that I can think of without actual code.

@MayurEkbote I added the component razor (can't hurt). But here's a fundamental question - shouldn't it be impossible for a call to await Task.Delay(1) to deadlock? By definition the code that called it is not locked, so that call should be free to run.

You are assuming that there is a deadlock in Task.Delay(1). My guess is that the deadlock is happening in the RenderFragment delegate that is rendering the component. In async initialization, the component is rendered fully before the await and then it is re-rendered after await returns. My hunch is that there is a deadlock happening during the first render before the await is called. Hence Task.Delay(1) never returns.

Btw, since you are using DevExp component - it seems that it uses JSInterop to render th e component (PositionTarget="body" implies that - there is no way to do it natively in Blazor). In case JSInterop causes an issue, it will never show up on the app. Check the browser console if there is an issue.

h/t to @MayurEkbote as they sent me down the road of removing components from the page to find if it was one of them. It was.
I had:
<DxComboBox Data="@EditModel.AllowedWorkplaces"
            ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)"
            InputId="workplace"
            TextFieldName="@nameof(EventPageModelBase.WorkplaceItem.Text)"
            name="@nameof(EventPageEditModel.Workplace)"
            autocomplete="off"
            SelectedItemChanged="@((EventPageModelBase.WorkplaceItem workplace) => OnWorkplaceClick(workplace))"
            @bind-Value="@EditModel.Workplace">Workplace</DxComboBox>

and the problem was that EditModel.AllowedWorkplaces was an array of enum values and EditModel.Workplace was the selected enum. I changed it to create a class that wraps the enum and have the combobox use that class. And it now works.
The error only occurs if SelectedItemChanged is specified. If that is not specified it works fine with an enum.
I have no idea why. Reading the documentation for DxComboBox it never mentions a collection of enums. So this may no longer be supported.
ps - The TextFieldName attribute was added with the change. Originally it did not have that attribute. But that is the only change in the razor code.

Thanks for the h/t. It is one of the reasons I have avoided using third party off the shelf libraries for Blazor. Most are opaque, some are poor wrappers around their existing JS libraries and all have poor API doc. I only use them for very complicated components like charts or specific corner cases. Otherwise, in my experience, using plain components + css + data binding fulfills all the needs.
